# DataGrid - How to display the content of a hidden TemplateField on mouseover

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm using a DataGrid to display informations (e.g. names and addresses of bookstores), and i want to display the opening hours in a tooltip onmouseover. The information i want to show onmouseover is in a TemplateField which Visible porperty is set to false.

How can i achieve that? Must i use javascript and css ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you won't be able to do it serverside, so it's javascript and css.

The easiest way to do it is probably to set the `Visible` attribute to `true` again (I don't know exactly how it is hidden...), and then apply a style class to the `<div>` that you want to pop up:

```
.hidden
{
     display: none; 
}
```

Also, give the `<div>` and `id` (it has to be unique for the markup to validate). You can then use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), a neat javascript library that makes a lot of things easier when writing client-side code, to show and hide the tooltip with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#theMouseOverElement').hover(
        function() {
            $('#theToolTip').show();
        },
        function() {
            $('#theToolTip').hide();
        }
    );
});
```

If the above code looks like jibberish to you, take a look at the jQuery [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works), and especially the [hover](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects) and [show/hide](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover#overout) functions.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to "see" the content of your TemplateField because when you set the `Visible` property to false in the aspx, the html won't even be rendered and thus won't be available on the client.

What you want is put the content you want to hide/show inside a `<div>` tag, invisible by default by setting the `display: hidden;` in a css class, then use JavaScript to change the display property dynamically, and also the position if you want your "tooltip" to appear near the mouse.

Here is a [link](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/) to a webcasts series that shows how to do this (among other things) using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)